# How to Set Minimum Column width ColumnResizable Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I Need to set minimum column width for a table while resizing i am using colresizable

```
  $('#Paid').colResizable({
        liveDrag: true
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going on [plugin documentation page](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#attributes), you can find this:

```
minWidth: [type: number] [default: 15] [version: 1.1]
```

> This value specifies the minimum width (measured in pixels) that is
>   allowed for the columns.

Comment: `$('#Paid').colResizable({
    liveDrag: true, minWidth: 20
});`